# Filtering or Querying Pandas MultiIndex Dataframe based on column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, multi-index

I have a multi-index pandas DataFrame such as below, primarily indexed with DateTime object.

```
>>> type(feed_tail)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

>>> feed_tail.index
DatetimeIndex(['2022-11-11', '2022-11-14', '2022-11-15', '2022-11-16',
           '2022-11-17', '2022-11-18', '2022-11-21', '2022-11-22',
           '2022-11-23', '2022-11-24'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)


>>> feed_tail.columns
MultiIndex([(       'Close', 'BALKRISIND.NS'),
        (       'Close',        'KSB.NS'),
        (       'SMA13', 'BALKRISIND.NS'),
        (       'SMA13',        'KSB.NS'),
        ('ClosegtSMA13', 'BALKRISIND.NS'),
        ('ClosegtSMA13',        'KSB.NS'),
        (     'MTDPerf', 'BALKRISIND.NS'),
        (     'MTDPerf',        'KSB.NS')],
       names=['Attributes', 'Symbols'])

>>> feed_tail
Attributes         Close                  SMA13           ClosegtSMA13              MTDPerf
Symbols    BALKRISIND.NS   KSB.NS BALKRISIND.NS   KSB.NS BALKRISIND.NS KSB.NS BALKRISIND.NS KSB.NS
Date
2022-11-11       1889.45  1834.40       1933.03  1959.00         False  False         -3.73 -11.86
2022-11-14       1875.55  1848.60       1927.28  1944.42         False  False         -4.44 -11.18
2022-11-15       1963.20  1954.15       1928.51  1938.12          True   True          0.02  -6.11
2022-11-16       1956.30  1969.75       1929.43  1933.65          True   True         -0.33  -5.36
2022-11-17       1978.35  1959.55       1932.08  1927.51          True   True          0.79  -5.85
2022-11-18       1972.75  1917.90       1932.85  1914.94          True   True          0.51  -7.85
2022-11-21       1945.80  1874.70       1932.80  1902.38          True  False         -0.86  -9.93
2022-11-22       1950.30  1882.85       1932.60  1892.80          True  False         -0.63  -9.54
2022-11-23       1946.60  1930.90       1936.52  1893.97          True   True         -0.82  -7.23
2022-11-24       1975.40  1925.80       1941.11  1901.10          True   True          0.64  -7.47
```

I am trying to access/filter the dataframe into another dataframe, for every datetime index in sequence where `ClosegtSMA13` column is `True` but seems like I am failing at understanding the datamodel here. Quest is to iterate over the datetime index in sequence, and get dataframes where the Symbols' `ClosegtSMA13` is `True` or `Close` is `greater than` `SMA13` with in the same dataframe and then go over the filtered/queried dataframe for further processing within the loop.

Any help towards unravelling this further is sincerely appreciated.

Thank you

Updates:

Following @jezrael's suggestion to use mask. This helps in performing the 'OR' operation in a way that prefers to get all series rows that have satisfying `Close gt SMA13` for all symbols though.

```
>>> feed_tail
Attributes         Close                  SMA13           ClosegtSMA13              MTDPerf
Symbols    BALKRISIND.NS   KSB.NS BALKRISIND.NS   KSB.NS BALKRISIND.NS KSB.NS BALKRISIND.NS KSB.NS
Date
2022-11-11       1889.45  1834.40       1933.03  1959.00         False  False         -3.73 -11.86
2022-11-14       1875.55  1848.60       1927.28  1944.42         False  False         -4.44 -11.18
2022-11-15       1963.20  1954.15       1928.51  1938.12          True   True          0.02  -6.11
2022-11-16       1956.30  1969.75       1929.43  1933.65          True   True         -0.33  -5.36
2022-11-17       1978.35  1959.55       1932.08  1927.51          True   True          0.79  -5.85
2022-11-18       1972.75  1917.90       1932.85  1914.94          True   True          0.51  -7.85
2022-11-21       1945.80  1874.70       1932.80  1902.38          True  False         -0.86  -9.93
2022-11-22       1950.30  1882.85       1932.60  1892.80          True  False         -0.63  -9.54
2022-11-23       1946.60  1930.90       1936.52  1893.97          True   True         -0.82  -7.23
2022-11-24       1975.40  1925.80       1941.11  1901.10          True   True          0.64  -7.47
>>> mask = feed_tail['Close'].gt(feed_tail['SMA13']).any(axis=1)
>>> df = feed_tail[mask]
>>> df
Attributes         Close                  SMA13           SMA13gtClose              MTDPerf
Symbols    BALKRISIND.NS   KSB.NS BALKRISIND.NS   KSB.NS BALKRISIND.NS KSB.NS BALKRISIND.NS KSB.NS
Date
2022-11-15       1963.20  1954.15       1928.51  1938.12          True   True          0.02  -6.11
2022-11-16       1956.30  1969.75       1929.43  1933.65          True   True         -0.33  -5.36
2022-11-17       1978.35  1959.55       1932.08  1927.51          True   True          0.79  -5.85
2022-11-18       1972.75  1917.90       1932.85  1914.94          True   True          0.51  -7.85
2022-11-21       1945.80  1874.70       1932.80  1902.38          True  False         -0.86  -9.93
2022-11-22       1950.30  1882.85       1932.60  1892.80          True  False         -0.63  -9.54
2022-11-23       1946.60  1930.90       1936.52  1893.97          True   True         -0.82  -7.23
2022-11-24       1975.40  1925.80       1941.11  1901.10          True   True          0.64  -7.47
```

*Overall quest* is associated with bigger shape of this dataframe model where I intend to get the top 'MTDPerf' items for each day and this seemingly helps but I would like to filter by making sure they have their 'Close gt SMA13' before checking for their MTDPerf values.

```
>>> for dt in feed_tail.index:
...     
feed_tail['MTDPerf'].loc[dt].head(10).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Trying to filter before going for MTDPerf related stuff,

```
>>> for dt in feed_tail.index:
...     d=feed_tail[feed_tail['Close'].loc[dt] > feed_tail['SMA13'].loc[dt]]
...     d
...
<stdin>:2: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3796, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_bool_array(key)
  File "lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3849, in _getitem_bool_array
    key = check_bool_indexer(self.index, key)
  File "lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2548, in check_bool_indexer
    raise IndexingError(
pandas.errors.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

**Solution (or approach used so far):** (many thanks to [@jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael) 's leading answer)

```
mmtd = feed_tail.where(feed_tail['Close'] > feed_tail['SMA13']).where(feed_tail['MTDPerf'] > 0)

for dt in mmtd.index:
    dt_str = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    a = mmtd.loc[dt_str, ['Close', 'MTDPerf']]
    a = a[a.notna()]
    unstacked_a = a.unstack(0)
    if not unstacked_a.empty:
        unstacked_a = unstacked_a.sort_values(by=(['MTDPerf']), ascending=False)
        print(dt_str, unstacked_a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with filter `MTDPerf` `Series`:

```
for dt in feed_tail.index:
    mmtd = feed_tail.loc[dt, 'MTDPerf']
    d = mmtd[feed_tail.loc[dt, 'Close'] > feed_tail.loc[dt, 'SMA13']]
```

---

```
    print (d)

Series([], Name: 2022-11-11 00:00:00, dtype: object)
Series([], Name: 2022-11-14 00:00:00, dtype: object)
Symbols
BALKRISIND.NS    0.02
KSB.NS          -6.11
Name: 2022-11-15 00:00:00, dtype: object
Symbols
BALKRISIND.NS   -0.33
KSB.NS          -5.36
Name: 2022-11-16 00:00:00, dtype: object
Symbols
BALKRISIND.NS    0.79
KSB.NS          -5.85
Name: 2022-11-17 00:00:00, dtype: object
Symbols
BALKRISIND.NS    0.51
KSB.NS          -7.85
Name: 2022-11-18 00:00:00, dtype: object
Symbols
BALKRISIND.NS   -0.86
Name: 2022-11-21 00:00:00, dtype: object
Symbols
BALKRISIND.NS   -0.63
Name: 2022-11-22 00:00:00, dtype: object
Symbols
BALKRISIND.NS   -0.82
KSB.NS          -7.23
Name: 2022-11-23 00:00:00, dtype: object
Symbols
BALKRISIND.NS    0.64
KSB.NS          -7.47
Name: 2022-11-24 00:00:00, dtype: object()
```

Solution with [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) for replace `NaN`s if no match:

```
df = feed_tail['MTDPerf'].where(feed_tail['Close'] > feed_tail['SMA13'])
print (df)
Symbols     BALKRISIND.NS  KSB.NS
2022-11-11            NaN     NaN
2022-11-14            NaN     NaN
2022-11-15           0.02   -6.11
2022-11-16          -0.33   -5.36
2022-11-17           0.79   -5.85
2022-11-18           0.51   -7.85
2022-11-21          -0.86     NaN
2022-11-22          -0.63     NaN
2022-11-23          -0.82   -7.23
2022-11-24           0.64   -7.47
```

And after reshaping:

```
s = feed_tail['MTDPerf'].where(feed_tail['Close'] > feed_tail['SMA13']).stack()
print (s)
            Symbols      
2022-11-15  BALKRISIND.NS    0.02
            KSB.NS          -6.11
2022-11-16  BALKRISIND.NS   -0.33
            KSB.NS          -5.36
2022-11-17  BALKRISIND.NS    0.79
            KSB.NS          -5.85
2022-11-18  BALKRISIND.NS    0.51
            KSB.NS          -7.85
2022-11-21  BALKRISIND.NS   -0.86
2022-11-22  BALKRISIND.NS   -0.63
2022-11-23  BALKRISIND.NS   -0.82
            KSB.NS          -7.23
2022-11-24  BALKRISIND.NS    0.64
            KSB.NS          -7.47
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, thank you for response. My apologies, I have updated my question about query for Close gt SMA13, however I am not really sure the mask is filtering... I will have to iterate over datetime index as sequence anyways. This, however, does weed out the frames that does not satisfy 'Close' > 'SMA13' for all symbol columns.

Comment: @NikhilMulley - what days should be in ouput from sample data? Id necessary filter only by `SMA13gtClose` mask?

Comment: we can go over each date in loop (datetime index as sequence) and check

Comment: @NikhilMulley - What is expected ouput? Can you add to question?

Comment: overall quest is related to a bigger dataframe where I would like to sort the symbols by their MTDPerf for each day and this is seemingly achieved with
    >>> for dt in new_y_price_feed.index:
    ...
 
 
 
 print(new_y_price_feed['MTDPerf'].loc[dt].head(10).sort_values(ascending=False))

but I would like to make sure that those are filtered for their 'Close gt SMA13' before checking on their MTDPerf column

Comment: Hi @jezrael, I have added to the updates in the question

Comment: @NikhilMulley -I dont understand `but I would like to filter by making sure they have their 'Close gt SMA13' before checking` - what does it mean?

Comment: @NikhilMulley - It means is necessary use mask from `SMA13gtClose` for `MTDPerf` and if `False` is necessary remove from top10? Or something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250084/discussion-between-nikhil-mulley-and-jezrael).

Comment: @NikhilMulley - thank you for code, answer was edited.

Comment: This is awesome! thanks!! this lead me to do this:


`>>> mmtd = feed_tail.where(feed_tail['Close'] > feed_tail['SMA13']).where(feed_tail['MTDPerf'] > 0)
    >>> for dt in mmtd.index:
    ...     r=mmtd['MTDPerf'].loc[dt].head(10).sort_values(ascending=False)
    ...     print(r)`

Comment: @NikhilMulley - Or chain mask by `|` for bitwise `OR` - `mmtd = feed_tail.where((feed_tail['Close'] > feed_tail['SMA13']) | (feed_tail['MTDPerf'] > 0))`